# Incorrect memory bandwidth when using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, gpu, hardware

I was wondering whether this memory bandwidth amount is correct. I have an NVDIA RTX 3090 and, in theory, it's bandwidth should be around 936.2 GB/s. However, when using TensorFlow, it appears significantly lower. Is there any limitation or is this how it should be?
My current bus interface is PCIe x16 4.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OLVT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

871.81 gibibyte (GiB) ~= 936.1 gigabyte (GB)

So the bandwidth reported by Tensorflow is about the same (0.1 GB/s difference) as the official specification of the card. I suspect the 0.1 difference is just rounding or precision loss somewhere.